# Google Cloud VPN Tunnel: The request contains invalid arguments: "undefined". Error code: "undefined"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn, gcloud, tunnel, google-cloud-vpn

After creating a Google Cloud VPN Tunnel, I get the following cryptic error message:

> The request contains invalid arguments: "undefined". Error code: "undefined"

Does anyone know what this error message can mean or how one would go about debugging it? Screenshots of our settings and error message are below. Is there anything obviously wrong in our settings? How would one debug this?

---

### Settings for the VPN Tunnel:

[image: settings]

### Error Message After Setup

[image: Error Message]

### Row for Setup:

[image: Error Row]

Comment: In your account go to notification and on bottom list all activity.. check your tunnel logs you will see reason for this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I checked the activity log. I'm creating the VPN through the web console, and it fails when creating a route. But there's no place to specify route details during setup. I'm just getting this message: `Invalid value for field 'resource.destRange': ''. is not a valid IPv4 address range.` Looks like it's missing an IP range for the route, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the VPN tunnel using the Google Shell[1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/vpn-tunnels/create):

> gcloud beta compute vpn-tunnels create

Use the '-verbosity' and share the result here.

---